# Best way to separate values in a large flat file

Tags: java, database

I'm creating a DBMS (basically a software handling SQL queries) strictly for fun and as a learning experience. And I need to know the best way to separate values and rows.

For the table configuration I use XML as it's a good way to store information. Although this can not be done with all inserted rows as all the xml tags will take up a LOT of memory. I also thought about serializing all the objects representing a database (as I use Java) to store the data but my guess is that that too would take up a lot of memory.

So the only thing I could think of was using some value separator and row separator to take up minimum amount of memory. Although the problem with separators as single-characters (if I use multicharacter I might as well use XML) is that problems will occur if that separator is in one of the values. So I thought about if I could use a hexadecimal character with no attached symbol. Does that exist? And if so, is it a good approach? One problem is if I, in the future, starts allowing BLOBs. Those contain binary data and might contain my value separator. What is the best solution to this?

Tell me what you think! I'm open for discussion. Also, if anyone knows how MySQL (or some other widely used SQL engine) stores data, that could be interesting.

## A new idea I got

What if you can read the entire table into a TreeSet loaded with different comparators based on what you are searching on/order by. Then the search would be equally fast what ever you are searching on. The downside of this is of course that the whole file will have to be written into objects that are placed in the TreeSet, could be a lot of RAM. What do you think?

Comment: What kind of a DBMS are you creating? Is it relational, with data stored in tables with a fixed schema, or something else?

Comment: It's relational with tables, much like MySQL. Although i have future plans on creating nested results, so a column referencing a row on a diffrent table will contain the row from the other table. But the data is still stored in tables.

Comment: Start with data structures you need to save and load data into records, then think to optimize retrieval of data with building b-tree indexes.

Comment: The tree set idea is pretty reasonable, if you have a known amount of data, which must be available for fast accesses. Otherwise, one could try to get a disk backed tree implementation, if query complexity can be handled in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that came to my mind are indexes. If you keep up developing your DBMS, you will encounter the need for various types of indexes anyway (binary trees, hash maps, etc.). An index would require straight mapping of contents to be effective. Scanning a file sequentially for rows won't be.

- If your rows have fixed length (depends on table data definition), you could have fixed offsets from record to record and also among columns.
- If the length of a record varies, you would have the possibility to handle the fixed length columns the same way as described above. For dynamically sizeable fields, there could be a fixed size reference (offset value) to another section within the file, containing the dynamically sized values. A zero reference could be treated as NULL, as your file will most probably have a header.
- The other option is to maintain a row index with individual offsets to the row data, perhaps with 2^N granularity (paging). The offsets should match the alignment of actual data, especially if one does map a file into memory. To get started, that index could be a simple, ordered list for binary searches, maybe in a separate file. However, this would require some column delimiters as you stated. I'd go with sort of a field length encoding, as it doesn't require special treatment (such as escaping) of actual field contents. It would probably be effective to maintain the field lengths in another structure, which is mapped by or directly embedded in that index (as the number of dynamic columns is fixed). A negative field length could also designate a NULL value.
- You could look into the implementation of sqlite for ideas, as it has a very compact storage layout.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the ideas, I didn't even think of creating a datastructure even though that is obviously the best approach. Although I am wondering about saving information about the value length as 2^N. Am I supposed to fill up the spots to the value length with spaces? That will fill the file with an average of 1/4 of spaces.

Comment: You're welcome! What I meant is snapping the row offsets to some data type friendly alignment, e.g. 8 bytes for `uint64_t`, or 16 bytes for `long double` columns (recommended), while one could additionally map the data in kind of 'storage pages', with even larger alignment, perhaps the same as the OS page size (4096 bytes as on my box). This would reduce 'physical page overlaps' to a minimum when doing memory mapped file IO; less page misses > more speed. Filling with spaces is not required. There could be zeros (`'0'`s) or even garbage, as you'd skip those intermediate sections (padding).`